# Pass arguments in scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Can someone provide an example on how to use

```
scope
```

and parameters?

For example:

```
class Permission < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :default_permissions, :conditions => { :is_default => true }
end
```

I have this code that returns the default_permissions and I want to convert it to return the default permissions for a given user (user_id)

Thanks

Answer (score 83, accepted):

new syntax (ruby 1.9+), that will prevent errors even if you don't supply the user -

```
scope :default_permissions_for, ->(user = nil) { ... }
```

Comment: very helpful info. So does this mean when the argument is nil, the block doesn't execute? Ruby just behaves that way?

Comment: nope, it only means that the user will get a default value of nil if no value is given.
the block will run, but you could check if user.nil?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Heh, that's what the wording made it sound like, even though my ruby logic was screaming, "Wouldn't nil just get passed in as the argument?"

Answer (score 39):

Use lambda scopes:

```
scope :default_permissions_for, lambda{|user| { :conditions => { :user_id => user.id, :is_default => true } }
```

Be careful because not passing a parameter to a lambda when it expects one will raise an exception.

Comment: Is it possible to show an example on how to catch this exception in the controller? Or it's not necessary?

Comment: i'm not sure about exception name, check it in your logs and just do rescue ExceptionClass => e

Comment: @keymone in ruby 1.9 you can set a default for the lambda parameter to avoid those errors you're referring to. So it would be lambda{|user = nil| { :conditions......