# Include only the latest/newest associated record with active record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, scope

is it possible to load only the latest associated record of an associated table?

an example:

```
class author
  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :birthday
  has_many :books
end

class book
  attr_accessible :pages, :date of publication, :title
  belongs_to :author
end
```

Is there a way to generate a scope to load only the newest released book the author wrote? Or the book with the most pages?

I know, that I could include or join all books. But I don't know if its possible to load only a specific book for each author.

So that I could do a query like this:

```
Author.authors_and_their_newest_book
```

So that I could get these results

```
first_name_author_1, last_name_author_1, birthday_author_1, pages_book_3, date_of_publication_book_3, title_book_3
first_name_author_2, last_name_author_2, birthday_author_2, pages_book_5, date_of_publication_book_5, title_book_5
first_name_author_3, last_name_author_3, birthday_author_3, pages_book_9, date_of_publication_book_9, title_book_9
```

...

update:
I realize that my real problem isn't solved by answering this question.

There is a third model which I have to consider.

```
class author
  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :birthday
  has_many :books
end

class book
  attr_accessible :pages, :date of publication, :title, _genre_id
  belongs_to :author
  belongs_to :genre
end

class genre
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :books
end
```

My real problem is that I want to filter with a scope

```
scope :with_latest_book_is_a_thriller
scope :with_latest_book_is_a_science_fiction
scope :with_latest_book_is_a_genre_xyz
...
```

I thought when I have a scope with the latest book for each author I could chain it with another scope for the genre_id. But That leads to a results table where I don't have "authors in case their latest book is genre xyz" but "authors and their latest book from genre xyz".

So for example I have following authors with their books:

```
author_1: Bruce Wayne  
books:   
title: "how to fight a villain",date_of_publication: March 2010,genre: self-help,  
title: "my life as batman",date_of_publication: April 2012,genre: biography,  
title: "developing high tech equipment", date_of_publication: January 2013, genre: science  

author_2: Clark Kent  
books:  
title: "how I crossed the universe", date_of_publication: January 2009, genre: biography,  
title: "controlling a freezing breath", date_of_publication: February 2012, genre: self-help,  
title: "Clark Kent as Batman", date_of_publication: December 2013, genre: fiction  

author_3: Peter Parker  
books:  
title: "Spider-Man's life", date_of_publication: January 2010, genre: biography,  
title: "how to handle a life with a clone", date_of_publication: February 2011, genre: self-help,  
title: "Spider-Man is becoming a baker", date_of_publication: November 2013, genre: fiction
```

I want following results:

```
scope :with_latest_book_is_a_self_help => empty result  
scope :with_latest_book_is_a_biography => empty result  
scope :with_latest_book_is_a_science => Bruce Wayne, "developing high tech equipment"  
scope :with_latest_book_is_a_fiction => Clark Kent, "Clark Kent as Batman"; Peter Parker, "Spider-Man is becoming a baker"
```

But what I get is:

```
scope :with_latest_book_is_a_self_help => Bruce Wayne, "how to fight a villain"; Clark Kent, "controlling a freezing breath"; Peter Parker, "how to handle a life with a clone"
```

How can i realize that? Or is it not possible?

Comment: Did my answer worked for you?

Comment: Will try it in in a few minutes :)

Comment: Try my updated answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a working scope with lambda to pass parameters to the scope to select the genre id.

```
scope :latest_with_genre, lambda do |searched_genre_id|
  joins(:books)
    .where('books.date_of_publication = (SELECT MAX(books.date_of_publication) FROM books WHERE books.author_id = authors.id)')
    .where("books.genre_id = #{searched_genre_id}").group('author.id')
end
```

This answer [Rails query through association limited to most recent record?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5263322/1835865) from 
[Pan Thomakos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/427733/pan-thomakos) helped me for the scope.
This answer [Pass arguments in scope](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6788271/1835865) from [keymone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/166029/keymone) helped me for passing argument

Comment: Thank you for this answer! For rails 5.2 it causes `NoMethodError: undefined method 'expr' for nil:NilClass`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57074698/how-are-joins-in-scopes-in-rails-5-2-different-from-rails-5-1 for the details. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

I guess this should work

```
class author
  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :birthday
  has_many :books

  scope :latest, joins(:books).where('books.author_id = authors.id').order('date_of_publication DESC').group('authors.id')
end
```

**Update**

For your updated question,you need a scope like this in `Book` model.

```
class book
  attr_accessible :pages, :date of publication, :title, _genre_id
  belongs_to :author
  belongs_to :genre

  scope :latest_with_genre, joins(:author,:genre).where("author_id =?","genre_id =?,author.id,genre.id).order('date_of_publication DESC').group('author.id','genre.id')

end
```

This should work i guess.

Comment: This only gives me one author with his newest book, but not all authors with their newest book. I think in my question it was not clear, that I wanted all authors. So I added some more details.

Comment: @railsnewbie Try my updated answer! I just removed `limit(1)`.

Comment: I tried that too, that gives me all authors with all books in order. But I only wanted the newest one. One entry per author in my results.

    1. Author.joins(:books)..count => 1204
    2. Author.joins(:books).order('date_of_publication Desc').count  => 1204

Comment: @railsnewbie Try giving just `Author.latest`

Comment: gives me an NoMethodError: undefined method `latest' for #<Class:0x00000007f61498> Do you mean last? With last I only get the latest author with no join options.

Comment: No! I mean the `latest` only.Do you defined the `scope` in the `Author` model?

Comment: oh, sorry. Now I know what you mean. No I just tried the query in the console. Will try it with the scope now.

Comment: Author.latest.count => 1204. Still an entry for each book the authors had written.

Comment: try like this `Author.joins(:books).where('books.author_id => author.id).order('date_of_publication DESC')`

Comment: I had to adjust the where clause a little bit.  
    Author.joins(:books).where('books.author_id = authors.id).order('date_of_publication DESC').

But     Author.latest.count is still 1204.

Comment: That works. But I realize that this doesn't solves my initial problem. I will update my question.

Comment: @railsnewbie Initial problem? What is that?

Comment: I updated my question. So I hope it is clear now what I mean with my "initial problem"

Comment: Why do you put the author_id in the where clause? I want to use it to get all authors with a latest book from genre xyz. So I changed your solution to `scope :latest_with_genre, joins(:author,:genre).where("genre_id = 1").order('date_of_publication DESC').group('books.author_id','books.genre_id')`. But this gives me the previous result where I have "authors and their latest book from genre xyz".

Comment: @railsnewbie Give `genre_id = genre.id` and check.

Comment: When I change it to `scope :latest_with_genre, joins(:author,:genre).where("genre_id = genre.id").order('date_of_publication DESC').group('books.author_id','books.genre_id')` I get nearly all books. And how do i specify the genre? Not sure how do you mean it.

Comment: I think I have the answer. I will post it now

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery composed via Arel to select the most recent published book for the join, e.g. something like this:

```
has_one :latest_book, -> { order(published_at: :desc) }, class_name: 'Book'
scope :with_latest_book, -> {
  books = Book.arel_table
  latest_book_publication = books.project(books[:published_at].maximum).where(books[:author_id].eq(arel_table[:id]))
  left_joins(:books).where(books[:published_at].eq(latest_books)).includes(:books)
}
```