# How are joins in scopes in Rails 5.2 different from rails 5.1?

Tags: join, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5.2

After I upgraded rails from 5.1 to 5.2 I started getting the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `expr' for nil:NilClass
  from /gems_path/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/associations/join_dependency/join_association.rb:47:in `block in join_constraints'
  from /gems_path/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/associations/join_dependency/join_association.rb:33:in `reverse_each'
  from /gems_path/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/associations/join_dependency/join_association.rb:33:in `join_constraints'
  from /gems_path/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/associations/join_dependency.rb:167:in `make_constraints'
  from /gems_path/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/associations/join_dependency.rb:177:in `make_join_constraints'
  from /gems_path/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/associations/join_dependency.rb:104:in `block in join_constraints'
  from /gems_path/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/associations/join_dependency.rb:103:in `each'
  from /gems_path/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/associations/join_dependency.rb:103:in `flat_map'
  from /gems_path/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/associations/join_dependency.rb:103:in `join_constraints'
  from /gems_path/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:1026:in `build_join_query'
  from /gems_path/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:1008:in `build_joins'
  from /gems_path/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:928:in `build_arel'
  from /gems_path/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:903:in `arel'
  from /gems_path/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/relation.rb:554:in `block in exec_queries'
  from /gems_path/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/relation.rb:578:in `skip_query_cache_if_necessary'
  from /gems_path/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/relation.rb:542:in `exec_queries'
  from /gems_path/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/relation.rb:414:in `load'
  from /gems_path/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/relation.rb:200:in `records'
  from /gems_path/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:41:in `[]'
```

The code which causes the error looks the following way:

```
class Post
  has_many :comments

  has_one :last_comment, -> {
    joins("LEFT JOIN posts on posts.id = comments.post_id")
    .where("
      comments.id = (
        SELECT MAX(comments.id) FROM comments
        WHERE comments.post_id = posts.id
      )"
    )
  }, class_name: "Comment"

  scope :with_last_comment, -> { joins(:last_comment) }
end
```

I created [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Hirurg103/7b6bcffaf5478675d97c6e472cb17a4e) which contains full code which helps to reproduce the bug. Download `issue_with_joins_in_scopes_in_rails_5_3.rb` to your PC and run it with

```
ruby issue_with_joins_in_scopes_in_rails_5_3.rb
```

You can look at [this Github issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/32671) for more details

What is the difference between joins in Rails 5.2 and 5.1 which causes the code `Post.with_last_comment` to fail with error in Rails 5.2?

How can I change `last_comment` association and `with_last_comment` scope in the Post model so it will work in Rails 5.2?

Answer (score 0):

Posting partial solution on how to preload last comment for a collection of posts

First you will need to have the following `last_comment` association:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy

  has_one :last_comment, -> { order(id: :desc) }, class_name: "Comment"
end
```

It works with `preload` and `includes` in Rails 5.2 and generates the following SQL queries:

```
Post.includes(:last_comment)

Post Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
Comment Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."post_id" = ? ORDER BY "comments"."id" DESC  [["post_id", 1]]
```

The problem with this solution is that when I use `joins` it ignores association scope and generates the following SQL query:

```
Post.joins(:last_comment)

Post Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" INNER JOIN "comments" ON "comments"."post_id" = "posts"."id" LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
```

I was able to solve it changing the original `last_comment` association the following way:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy

  has_one :last_comment, -> {
    joins(:post)                               # <--- Note this change
    .where("
      comments.id = (
        SELECT MAX(comments.id) FROM comments
        WHERE comments.post_id = posts.id
      )"
    )
  }, class_name: "Comment"

  scope :with_last_comment, -> { joins(:last_comment) }
end
```

And now `Post.with_last_comment` generates the following SQL:

```
Post Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" INNER JOIN "comments" ON "comments"."post_id" = "posts"."id" INNER JOIN "posts" "posts_comments" ON "posts_comments"."id" = "comments"."post_id" AND (
      comments.id = (
        SELECT MAX(comments.id) FROM comments
        WHERE comments.post_id = posts.id
      )) LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
```

The question on how joins in Rails 5.2 are different from Rails 5.1 is still open